# Is std::transform_reduce without execution policy portable?

Tags: c++

I can compile the following code (using `std::transform_reduce`) with gcc 9.2.1 on both Fedora and Ubuntu, but attempting to compile on clang [see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wFAUxx) fails, and I've got a report that some FSF version of gcc 9.2.1 also refuses to compile the code, requiring a `std::execution_policy` as the first argument to the `std::transform_reduce`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

auto brokenvector(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> const& b) 
{
  return std::transform_reduce(cbegin(a), cend(a), cbegin(b), 0, std::plus<>{},std::multiplies<>{});
}
```

I specifically cannot use a `std::execution_policy` here, and both [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) and the C++ draft standard document n4659 show overloads *without* an execution policy.

Have I stepped into some kind of political minefield where half of the available compilers refuse to implement the standard, or is the code incorrect?

Comment: C++17 is (relatively) new. I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is simply: Some library implementers just didn't implement this yet

Comment: So it is portable as long as compilers/libraries respect (implement fully) the standard.

Comment: [this question and its answers may be interesting for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567998/how-do-i-use-the-new-c17-execution-policies/42587914#comment86495939_42587914)

Comment: @CássioRenan That's kind of the opposite of my problem, I explicitly do *not* want to specify an execution policy. Furthermore, while the answer "C++17 is not yet fully supported" was entirely reasonable in 2017, it's a bit less understandable in 2020. My understanding of the C++ evolution was that the goal is to have most new features already implemented in multiple compilers before standardizing them, and to me as a mostly-C-developer std::algorithm seems like the crown jewel of recent c++ standards. This is baffling to me.

Comment: @EOF I know. I thought you would think it was interesting because it exemplifies your issue: That standard features may take a (sometimes long) while to actually be implemented (If you look at one of the comments there, MSVC took over 6 years to finish support of C++11!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a libstdc++ vs libc++ issue.  libc++ implements [the function](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/numeric#L49) and you can see it working with clang on godbolt using `-stdlib=libc++` in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/SGvr4_).  gcc implements it now in [trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/TCuwTy), but the currently released versions do not.  The function was added in [this commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/b93041f0d3c9a2fc64f0f5fb538e78d5e2001d32).

Comment: @walnut Thanks for that.  Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Interesting that both Ubuntu 19.10 and Fedora 31 apparently have libstdc++-versions that already include this function. Either way, this answer should be very useful for me.