# C++ 17 programming on visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

In title, I am specific about the task that I want to achieve. I want to utilize the c++17 features such as parallel STL etc. On visual studio 2017, I configure to c++17 under project properties for language. Even after doing this I get the error with #include  that no execution file.
I am just starting with simple example of array addition in parallel with C++ 17 algorithms. How do I resolve this?

Source:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <ratio>
#include <vector>

using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::milli;
using std::random_device;
using std::sort;
using std::vector;


const size_t testSize = 1'000'000;
const int iterationCount = 5;

void print_results(const char *const tag, const vector<double>& sorted,
    high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime,
    high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime) {
    printf("%s: Lowest: %g Highest: %g Time: %fms\n", tag, sorted.front(),
        sorted.back(),
        duration_cast<duration<double, milli>>(endTime - startTime).count());
}

int main() {
    random_device rd;

    // generate some random doubles:
    printf("Testing with %zu doubles...\n", testSize);
    vector<double> doubles(testSize);
    for (auto& d : doubles) {
        d = static_cast<double>(rd());
    }

    // time how long it takes to sort them:
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; ++i)
    {
        vector<double> sorted(doubles);
        const auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
        const auto endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        print_results("Serial", sorted, startTime, endTime);
    }
}
```

and this is error:
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'execution': No such file or directory

Task that I want to achieve is that C++17 with CUDA GPU. Both new to me although not c++ in itself. But I am interested in parallel STL of C++17 with CUDA. I want to start from base. Any suggestions will help me?

Thanks,
Govind

Comment: show the source and the error message, " I get the error with #include that no execution file" is not clear at all

Comment: I edited my question with source and error. However, this is sorting example. In main function,  will replace for loop with std::execution::par , std::execution::seq to check out the performance of c++ 17 parallel algorithm. In project properties, I set language standard as "ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)".

Comment: See [How do I use the new C++17 execution policies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42567998/3422102) Unless you have the latest (or at least recent) updates to VS2017, you may not have the execution policies available.

Comment: @govindsharma Your code works on VS2017 MSVC 19.16.27045.0.

Comment: Works fine on old VS2017 on Win7. VS2017 ver. 15.9.44. Also works fine with gcc 11.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using 2017 15.3.3 version. That's why I am having problem. I tried with gcc-9 also but tbb gives me issue that I should  have newest version 2019. On my system, Ubuntu 18 is installed and tbb version 2017.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check if the header file is included in the header file directory. the C++ headers path are:

1.C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include

2.C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt

The first contains standard C++ headers such as iostream. The second contains legacy C headers such as stdio.h.

If you are going to use C++ to develop desktop applications, I recommend you to refer to my setup.

[image]

Also I tested your code on VS2022 without any errors. So I suggest you to use a higher version of VS and install the environment you need.

Comment: @Yao: Thanks. I checked the version of VS is 2017 15.3.3. And "execution" header file is also not there. I will try to do in higher version.